# GitHub project to Gitlab

Tags: github, gitlab

I want to pull a project from GitHub and to push it into my project on GitLab. Notice that the project on GitHub isn't mine. What should I do in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

According to GitLab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/repo_by_url.html), you can do this in the following steps:

1. From your GitLab dashboard click [New project](https://gitlab.com/projects/new)
2. Switch to the `Import project` tab
3. Click on the `Repo by URL` button
4. Fill in the "Git repository URL" and the remaining project fields
5. Click `Create project` to begin the import process
6. Once complete, you will be redirected to your newly created project

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the response. I have tried and it is working, even it wasn't working before.